# android programming for multiple device sizes

Tags: android, screen, device

I am relatively new to Android programming and am working on an app that will eventually span across all screen sizes using fragments.  I would like to encompass everything I do into a single app to make it easier for the user.

However my problem is that The app will act differently for screen sizes that are smaller vs ones that are bigger.

Example:
A smartphone of a phablet may use fragments to display a main menu screen, then a user  clicks an image button to open a new fragment that replaces the main menu and takes up the whole screen.  This is irregardless of orientation of the device

A tablet with a bigger screen (say 7 inches or bigger) will always show the main menu as a separate fragment to the left (landscape) or top (portrait) along side another fragment that is activated on the image button press.

Am I doomed to make separate versions of this app or can I get away with this using different layout folders and back end logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is make different layouts or each size in:

- layout-small (small phones like *Galaxy Pocket Neo*), layout-normal
  (phones with around         4 inch screens like *HTC One Mini*),
- layout-large (ranging from *Nexus 5* to phablets), and
- layout-xlarge (tablets from 7in to 10in).

Then, in the MainActivity or whatever activity you are using you could check if a certain fragment is there; if it is, the device is a **tablet** but if not the device is a **phone**. Then, you could launch the separate activity if it is a phone, etc.

Comment: That's about where my head was.  Using qualifiers to specify but I'm unsure if it's easier to do this or not because I want to try to define all my fragments in code and none in the layout files. But using this method I may have to do my fragments in XML.

Comment: Actually scratch that.  If I name all the files the same in each folder, the OS automatically goes to the folder that qualifies for the current view and grabs the XML does it not?

Answer (score 0):

What you're building sounds a lot like the [Master Detail Flow](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#master-detail-activity) paradigm, which is so common it is built into the SDK build tools. If you are using Android Studio just right click on your source folder then navigate to New -> Activity -> Master/Detail Flow. If you currently do not have a project set up then you can use the Master/Detail Flow as a project template and get started that way. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: That's a good plan but I have already started the project, and it looks like the master detail flow is using a listview.  I want to try to do this with nothing but image buttons and text views inside a scroll view.  I might be going from A to B by going though Z first but if I do it from scratch the hard way I'll probably learn more.  I will be bookmarking this link though, that's useful!  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your best read right here: [Google Developers: Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Also:  [Google Developers: Supporting Tablets and Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

You can have one app that's as responsive as you need and not have to worry about building out apks for different screen sizes, which would be a pain.

Comment: I'm hoping that's the case.  I'll definitely read these and bookmark.  Thanks for the finds :)